# Adding backorder status to specific option in CartThrob Price Modifiers Configurator

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

Using the Price Modifiers Configurator, I'm curious if it's possible to add a status to a specific option (based on inventory). Say backorder only red, XL tshirt and leave all other colors and sizes unaffected.

If not possible with the Price Modifiers Configurator, is it possible to use Matrix? Other suggestions?